# saving a web page that is served content through ajax as a pdf

Tags: javascript, ajax, printing

My webpage is loading all it's content through AJAX. In Chrome, when I go to print, it only displays the header and footer which are set and not served using AJAX (it's simply blank where the content is clearly visible in the browser). Is there a known solution to this, or documentation on AJAX and it's interaction with printing/saving from the browser?

Comment: There is no ajax + print specific behaviour. Printing just prints the current state of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at jquery printArea plugin
https://plugins.jquery.com/PrintArea/

We had a similar issue and the workaround we came up with was to create a hidden dom element (either a div or iframe) with all the content to print and used printArea to handle the printing

Comment: It's kind of working now, at least the content is showing up, if it's not completely jumbled as if the css meant absolutely nothing.

Did you run into this issue when you were using the jquery PrintArea plug-in? [this is one line on the actual page](http://imgur.com/ogAB0K2)